# Declaration of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration

If you were to declare some pointers like this:

```
int n, *p1, *p2;
double *p3;
```

Would we be able to determine if p1 = p2?

My understanding is that all this code tells us is that *p1 and *p2 are pointers that will point to an int. And that p1 and p2 will be ints.

Edit:
So this is from a c++ book, and the question asks:

Mark the following statements as True (correct) or False (incorrect):

(a) p1 = p2;

Comment: p1 and p2 are not ints, they have the same memory as int but they hold an address where an int can be stored

Comment: p1 = p2 is always true.

Comment: Are you sure it said `p1 = p2` (as opposed to `p1 == p2`)? If so, then you are not "determining if" anything

Comment: It said p1 = p2. I assume that they are using the "=" as a replacement for "equals", and not the assignment operator.

Comment: You cannot tell whetier `p1` is equals to `p2` unless `p1` and `p2` are initialized.

Comment: @ChristianD'Ovidio I would not be so sure about that assumption

Answer (score 3):

`p1` and `p2` are pointers to ints.
`*p1` and `*p2` when used in code will get the value pointed to by p1 and p2. You can test to see if the pointers are the same using `p1 == p2`, and to see if the values pointed to by them are the same using `*p1 == *p2`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just write `p1 == p2` to determine if p1 = p2.

`p1` and `p2` won't be ints. They are pointers though it *may be* implemented as integers *in some environments*.

Answer (score 0):

`p1` and `p2` are not literally integers. They point to / contain a location address in memory which may contain an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If p1 == p2 then it is also true that *p1 == *p2

Comment: The second statement may be undefined behaviour (e.g. if both are null pointers)

Comment: No, it's still true.

Comment: undefined behaviour is neither true nor false

Answer (score 0):

you've got it the other way round.

```
int *p1, *p2;
```

p1 and p2 are pointers
and 
*p1 and *p2 would be integers

now say

```
*p1 = 35;
*p2 = 35;
```

the values at the memory locations p1 and p2 are equal. p1 need not be equal to p2 though.

On the other hand

```
int *p1 = 0, *p2=0;
int a = 75;
p1 = &a;
p2 = p1;
```

now both p1 and p2 contain the address of `a` so p1 is equal to p2;